# How to increase The initial RAM size(16M) of PPC440 in linux 2.6 kernel

Tags: embedded-linux, ppc

I am building cuImage. When I try to put in openSSH, I run out of 16M RAM boundary which is set during early kernel turning on MMU, so it wont boot up. Can anyone tell me how to increase that? Inside wrapper, there is a size set to 0x1000000, but it does not help me after I try to increase it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout /arch/powerpc/mm/40x_mmu.c.

You should have 512MB of RAM mapped for instruction and data. What Im offering will not solve your problem. But it is a good place to start with a debugger or kprintf.